# Get extension file from local folder

Tags: c#, uwp

How to get extension file from local folder? I have many file on library folder on the package

BookAudio Class:

```
class BookAudio
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I mean is not on drive E:\ or another, but in a package folder "Library".
code:
StorageFolder library = await installedLocation.CreateFolderAsync ("library", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
And I want to take the extension into if, for example: if the extension pdf, then navigate to the page pdfView.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find extension of a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886866/how-to-find-extension-of-a-file)

Comment: If you want to get the file name extension of a file in UWP, you can use [StorageFile.FileType property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.filetype.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

try this 
[Path.GetExtension Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx)

```
string ext = Path.GetExtension("FilePath");
```

Or you can simply use this

```
string PathTofile = @"E:\POSAPP\POS\POS\bin\Debug\kjhs.exe";
string extension = PathTofile.Substring(PathTofile.LastIndexOf('.')+1, PathTofile.Length - PathTofile.LastIndexOf('.')-1);
```

Comment: I mean is not on drive E: \ or another, but in a package folder "Library".
code:
StorageFolder library = await installedLocation.CreateFolderAsync ("library", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
And I want to take the extension into if, for example: if the extension pdf, then navigate to the pdfView page.