# How to know the extension of documents/files?

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, linq

I need to know the extension of different documents and depending of the extensions take some decisions within my code: for example I can have this FileNames:

`commands to save.docx`
`Old Word.doc`
`rel.txt`
`test.pdf`

I know that using the `Contains()` method that comes with Linq I could do something but I'm afraid that using `Contains()` it will take a `.doc` extension even if is a `.docx` extension because `.doc` is a `substring` of `.docx`

I think that a better approach would be maybe a regular expression for this... Any suggestion?

I've done something like this but maybe a `RegEx` should be a better approach:

```
if (fileName.Contains(".pdf"))
{
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf; Content-Disposition, inline" + fileName);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping` method the mime type of the document. With that,you do not really need to get the file extension and write those if condition for all the different types.

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileName("SomeFileNameWithLongPath.pdf");
string mimeType= MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName );
```

If you really want the extension, you can use the `Path.GetExtension` method

```
var extension = Path.GetExtension("SomeFileNameWithLongPath.pdf");
```

Answer (score 4):

You will find what you seek [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1886876/1678437), using [Path.GetExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx)

Comment: Links are not good naswers, put relevant code to the question.

Comment: @mybirthname it shouldn't have been an answer at all, this should have been marked as duplicate, and in general, links to relevant information should be added with a quote, doesn't mean there shouldn't be a link.

Comment: @Dispersia Indeed. Fixed :)