# How to determine excel file type(.xlsx or .xlsm) from file data

Tags: c#, excel

My application needs to save a byte[] to disk, the issue is that I know it is an excel file but not what the correct file extension is. Is there a way I can tell if the file is .xls or .xlsx or .xlsm from the data itself?

Comment: If you can open it using the XML OpenSDK then it's at least .xlsx or .xlsm, if you can't, then it's .xls ... if you want to determine if it has macros (which means it's .xlsm) then determine if it has a VbaProjectPart ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.packaging.workbookpart.vbaprojectpart?view=openxml-2.8.1#documentformat-openxml-packaging-workbookpart-vbaprojectpart

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the extension of a file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886866/how-to-find-the-extension-of-a-file-in-c)

Comment: This could be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Could you explain how you ended up in this situation where you have a byte array but not knowing the extension? Perhaps there's a different/better solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing an extension method to determine the excel file type. This method is not perfect. It will only correctly detect a .xlsm file if the file has a macro.

```
private static string FindType(this byte[] file)
{
    using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(file))
    {
        var zf = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Read);
        if (zf.Entries.Any(e=>e.FullName.StartsWith("xl.")))
        {
            if (zf.Entries.Any(e=>e.FullName.Equals("xl/vbaProject.bin", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
                return ".xlsm";
            else 
                return ".xlsx";
        }
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that should work, even if the xlsm file does not have any macros.

If you open the xlsm/xlsx file as zip file, you will see it contains multiple sub-files.

```
filelist:
0:<ZipInfo filename='docProps/app.xml' compress_type=deflate filemode='?rw-------' file_size=177 compress_size=130>
1:<ZipInfo filename='docProps/core.xml' compress_type=deflate filemode='?rw-------' file_size=598 compress_size=265>
...
9:<ZipInfo filename='[Content_Types].xml' compress_type=deflate filemode='?rw-------' file_size=1089 compress_size=299>
```

If you open **[Content_Types].xml**
One line will either contain

```
<Override PartName="/xl/workbook.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.main+xml"/>
```

or

```
<Override PartName="/xl/workbook.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml"/>
```

- xlsm files will have
  **application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.main+xml**
- xlsx files will
  have **application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml**

(For types other than xlsx or xlsm this full list may be useful https://www.contractsfinder.service.gov.uk/apidocumentation/ResourceModel?modelName=FileType)